# Is $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$ a Hausdorff space?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras, lattices-in-lie-groups

The special linear group $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of $n \times n$ matrices with determinant $1$, with the group operations of ordinary matrix multiplication and matrix inversion. We denote by $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ the group of  $n \times n$ matrices  with integer entries and determinant equals 1. Note that  $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$  is a discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Let $G$ to be a topological group and $H$ to be a subgroup of $G$. We will say that a regular Borel measure $\mu$ on the quotient $G/H$ is a *left invariant Haar measure* if for all Borel sets $E \subseteq G/H$ and all $g \in G$ we have $\mu(gE) = \mu(E)$.

If $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group and $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup such that $G/H$  carries a finite left G-invariant Harr measure, then we say that  $\Gamma$ is a $\textbf{lattice}$ in $G$.

We have the following results:

1. $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is a lattice in $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Moreover, the quotiont  $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is not compact.
2. (Mahler Criterion) For a sequnece $(g_{m})_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$,  the sequence  $(\pi (g_{m}))_{m\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$  does not have a convergent subsequence if, and only if, there exists a sequence $v_{m} \in \mathbb{Z}^{n}$ with $v_{m} \neq 0$ such that $g_{m}(v_{m})$ tends to $0$.

where  $\pi\colon\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R}) \to  \operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is the natural projection.

The second result suggest to me that $\operatorname{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})/\operatorname{SL}(n, \mathbb{Z})$  is a Hausdorff space, but I can't find any reference. So, I do not know if it is true.

Thanks

Comment: The action of any discrete subgroup on the ambient (locally compact Hausdorff) topological group is always properly discontinuous. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186183/left-translation-on-lie-group-of-a-discrete-subgroup-is-properly-discontinuous

Comment: More generally for any topological group $G$ and closed subgroup $H$ the quotient $G/H$ is Hausdorff. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787022/quotient-of-a-topological-group-by-a-closed-subgroup-is-hausdorff

Comment: Thanks. But how to show that  $H$ is closed  in $G$ if $H$ is a  discrete subgroup of $G$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29515/why-is-every-discrete-subgroup-of-a-hausdorff-group-closed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To summarize the comments: Combining [Left translation on Lie group of a discrete subgroup is properly discontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186183/left-translation-on-lie-group-of-a-discrete-subgroup-is-properly-discontinuous), [Quotient of a topological group by a closed subgroup is Hausdorff](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787022/quotient-of-a-topological-group-by-a-closed-subgroup-is-hausdorff), [Why is every discrete subgroup of a Hausdorff group closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29515/why-is-every-discrete-subgroup-of-a-hausdorff-group-closed)

answers your question in affirmative: The quotient is Hausdorff.