# Why do we use closed subgroups of topological groups?

Tags: topological-groups

I have been working with Topological Groups and have noticed that the subgroups of real interest in the topic are the closed subgroups. I figured this is because closed subgroups inherit most of the nice properties of the groups we work on and the quotients as well. I just wanted to know if there was any other reasons that I may be overlooking or unaware of?

Comment: As you said, it is nice. For example, the [Closed Subgroup Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem).

Comment: It's because we want the quotient to be Hausdorff: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2787022/quotient-of-a-topological-group-by-a-closed-subgroup-is-hausdorff

Comment: Also worth pointing out is the fact that open subgroups are closed